# jquery mobile button background color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

here is my code of a jquery mobile button

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" style="color:green; background-color:red";>
  Search
</a>
```

I want to change button background color, i have tried inline style but its not working however text color changes normally.

thanks

Comment: any working code/example can help better to identify problem, if possible put this on jsfiddle

Answer (score 19):

Simply use "background:" instead of "background-color:"

```
<a href="[url]" data-role="button" style="background: green; color: white;">Search</a>
```

Tested it and it works like a charm.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for, for a simple override on one button only.

Comment: Any idea why `background` works and `background-color` doesn't?

Answer (score 8):

jQuery Mobile initialized widgets and adds HTML structure when you make a link into a button. You can use this structure to target button widgets and their descendant elements to change the styles we want to change:

HTML --

```
<a class="my-btn" data-role="button" href="#">
    Search
</a>
```

CSS --

```
.ui-page .ui-content .ui-btn.my-btn .ui-btn-inner {
    color      : green;
    background : red;
}​
```

This targets the `.ui-btn-inner` element which is a descendant of the `a.ui-btn` element (your original link, which I added the `my-btn` class to), which is in a jQuery Mobile pseudo-page and sets it's `background` and the text `color`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WZ9pf/

The text color was working for you before because it gets inherited by descendant elements, so if you set text `color` on the `body` element for example, all elements will receive that text `color` if you don't specify another one further down the tree.

So you can see what jQuery Mobile does to a link that gets turned into a button, here is what the above HTML turns into:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" class="my-btn ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-hover-c ui-btn-up-c" data-theme="c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">
            Search
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

**Also**, if you want to create gradients easily, here is a great tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Here is a red one I pulled from the pre-made gradients: http://jsfiddle.net/WZ9pf/1/

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample 'red' button.

Just add the data-theme="f" to your button tag and then this could be a recommended method where you can create your own theme-able buttons

```
.ui-btn-up-f, .ui-btn-hover-f, .ui-btn-down-f {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none; }

.ui-btn-up-f {
  border: 1px solid #711414;
  background: #ab2525;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #711414;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c44f4f, #ab2525);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #c45e5e), color-stop(1, #9e3939));
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#c44f4f', EndColorStr='#ab2525')"; }

.ui-btn-hover-f {
  border: 1px solid #6e0000;
  background: #b54a4a;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #690101;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d47272, #b54a4a);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #d47272), color-stop(1, #b54a4a));
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#d47272', EndColorStr='#b54a4a')"; }

.ui-btn-down-f {
  border: 1px solid #782323;
  background: #c44f4f;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #782323;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9e3939, #c44f4f);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #9e3939), color-stop(1, #c44f4f));
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#9e3939', EndColorStr='#c44f4f')"; }
```

Code reference from https://gist.github.com/1057852

Answer (score 2):

JQuery mobile styles are all applied using themes. When a link is added to a container, it is automatically assigned a theme swatch letter that matches its parent bar or content box to visually integrate the button into the parent container, like a chameleon.

So a button placed inside a content container with a theme of "a" (black in the default theme) will be automatically assigned the button theme of "a" (charcoal in the default theme).

You can view the existing themes here.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/buttons/buttons-themes.html

If you want to create your own you can use theme roller:
http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

If the button is defined as:

```
<button type="button" id="yourbutton">Hello</button>
```

Then the code to set the background is:

```
$('#yourbutton').parent().find('.ui-btn-inner').css("background-color",highcolor);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to override not only the background color but the background-image gradient to the color that you want it works perfect for me

```
.ui-btn {
    background: #00BCD4;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00BCD4, #00BCD4);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom, color-stop(0, #00BCD4), color-         stop(1, #00BCD4));
   color:#FFFFFF;
   text-shadow:0px 0px 0px ;
   font-size: 40px;
   border: none;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="my-btn">submit</button>
```

css

```
.my-btn {
   background:#ea5514 !important;
   color:#ffffff !important;
}​
```